# PySpark - Get week of quarter based on date column

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm creating a spark dataframe with the columns dates, week_of_month, week_of_quarter and week_of_year, but I have no idea of how to get the **week of quarter in pyspark**. So far, this is what I did:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2017-01-01', '2021-01-01')], ['start', 'end'])
df = df.withColumn('start', f.col('start').cast('date'))\
        .withColumn('end', f.col('end').cast('date'))

df2 = df.withColumn('dates', f.explode(f.expr('sequence(start, end, interval 1 day)'))).drop('start', 'end')

df_week = df2 \
    .withColumn('calwek_week_of_month', f.date_format(f.col("dates"), "W"))\
    .withColumn('calwek_week_of_year', f.weekofyear(f.col("dates")))\
    .sort(['dates'])
```

An example of the result I'm expecting (though, I need all the dates between 2017-01-01 and 2021-01-01):

```
  dates         week_of_month      week_of_year    week_of_quarter
2017-01-01            1                  1                1
2017-01-02            1                  1                1
2017-01-03            1                  1                1
2017-01-04            1                  1                1
... ... ... ...
2017-03-30            5                  13               13
2017-03-31            5                  13               13
2017-04-01            1                  13               13
2017-04-02            2                  14               1
... ... ... ...
2017-04-14            3                  15               2
2017-04-15            3                  15               2
2017-04-16            4                  16               3
2017-04-17            4                  16               3
```

Can someone help me to calculate and create the column **week_of_quarter** in pyspark, please?

Comment: Are all the quarters a consistent length? If not, is it specific dates it changes?

Comment: I mean more are the number of days within them consistent, or is there disparities between them?

Comment: Why is 2017-04-01 the 13th week of the first quarter? Are the quarters not strictly defined as starting on January 1, April 1, July 1, and October 1? Are you defining weeks as Sunday-Saturday, Monday-Sunday, or some other logic?

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction**:

This Post Explains how to create a new column that will calculate the week number of a Quarter.

***Business Case***

In many cases Business Analyst would like to track trends over time aggregated by quarters but broken down to the week within each quarter.

***Steps***

Enter the following code in the formula editor:

IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())<=13,WEEKNUM(TODAY())

ELSE IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())<=26,WEEKNUM(TODAY())-13,

ELSE IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())<=39,WEEKNUM(TODAY())-26,

ELSE IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())<=52,WEEKNUM(TODAY())-39,0))

**IN SPARK**

We will just translate the different conditions into spark dataframe column functions using when and otherwise:

```
 df_week = given_df \
        .withColumn('calwek_week_of_month', f.date_format(f.col("dates"), "W")) \
        .withColumn('calwek_week_of_year', f.weekofyear(f.col("dates"))) \
        .withColumn("week_quarters",
                    when(f.col("calwek_week_of_year") <= 13, f.col("calwek_week_of_year")).
                    otherwise(when(f.col("calwek_week_of_year") <= 26, f.col("calwek_week_of_year") - 13)
                        .otherwise(
                        when(f.col("calwek_week_of_year") <= 39, f.col("calwek_week_of_year") - 26).otherwise(
                            when(f.col("calwek_week_of_year") <= 59, f.col("calwek_week_of_year") - 39).otherwise(0))))).sort(['dates'])
```

Please verify () in when / otherwise clause I didn't verify :)

Here is an example of output:
[image]

Comment: So some year have 53 weeks and for example with OP date range, in 2020, the week number 14 is technically in the first quarter as the Monday of that week is before the 1st of April. I don`t know how important this is for OP, just a comment

Comment: I'm saying that the week number 14 in the year 2020 starts during quarter 1, while your code makes it part of quarter 2 (as you use 13 as the maximum number of week in a quarter). this is mostly because this year has 53 weeks according to the method `weekofyear`. I don't know how important it is for the person who asked.

Comment: ahh I see what you wanna say , thank you for the remark well 14 > 13 so  the second condition will be true => 14 <= 26 the quarter = 14 -13 = 1 ? is this what you mean

Comment: yes, week 14 will always ends in your second condition, while for some years it starts during Quarter 1, so maybe this week should stay at 14 and then the week 15 should be the first of Q2. as I said it really up to OP, it was just a comment to be aware of the fact